# Cygwin Terminal: FTP Connection (Password Input doesn't end)

Tags: shell, networking, ftp, terminal, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin shell to try to establish a TCP connection with a specific IP address.

After typing "ftp 'the ip address'"

I get prompted for the username/password.

When I enter the username and press enter, it prompts me for the password (as I expected).

However, when I input the password and press enter, it just jumps to the next line and acts as if the buffer is still waiting for more input. It keeps doing this, leading me to have to use Ctrl-C to get out of it.

Anyone know any possible issues? This is for a school project. One of the TA's says this is "expected behavior" ... however, I couldn't find anything on the internet about this issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're probably running the ftp command that comes with Windows, which doesn't work correctly in a Cygwin terminal. You can install the inetutils package to get Cygwin's own ftp client.

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/304541/how-to-install-new-packages-on-cygwin